# Convert uniqueidentifier value into string in Excel

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, vba

In my system I have sql-table called `PointList`. In this table I have one column called `PointGuid` and this column contains following values:

```
dercb32bfcb-3206-4d34-a720-d9e4d881751b
c57e3583-caed-41c3-9bd6-94254cc8912f
5fd2902d-04f7-4396-a7a2-b73229683dc4
4990b313-0955-410f-a7dd-8ba84c3f2f6a
fa67f181-6d1b-425a-8328-ee03f56c1524
96676b35-133a-4ad2-be0e-e99d50b018de
```

(This Value I read from Excel 2010, And my system have install SQL Server Configuration manager 2008)

I need to understand 'dercb32bfcb-3206-4d34-a720-d9e4d881751b'  what this uniqueidentifier have value (all the uniqueidentifier).

so I can directly pass this value from Excel to Database and automate stuff. Can any one help me

I have read on the Internet about uniqueidentifier but I don't get much.

Comment: Does your Excel spreadsheet also contains these values and you want to import them into database table OR your Excel spreadsheet does not have them and you want to know how to generate these values?

Comment: @Alex , Excel sheet contain this value, I import this value from Database(Using Excel 'From Sql Server' option) and I got this value.

Comment: They are GUID's - https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/27/sql-server-introduction-to-guids-sql-queries-2012-joes-2-pros-volume-3-advanced-query-tools-and-techniques-for-sql-server-2012/   There is nothing to "understand" from their actual value: they do not represent anything other than "a value very unlikely to be duplicated within a given system (or even outside of that system)"

Comment: @Tim Williams please add this comment as answer so I can accept it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are GUID's.  There is nothing to "understand" from their actual value: they do not represent anything other than "a value very unlikely to be duplicated within a given system (or even outside of that system)"

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/27/sql-server-introduction-to-guids-sql-queries-2012-joes-2-pros-volume-3-advanced-query-tools-and-techniques-for-sql-server-2012/